# Convert a mediawiki page to html with the table of contents working

Tags: pdf, conversion, mediawiki, table-of-contents, wiki

I am looking for a way to convert a page from **mediawiki** software (basically a web page very similar to wikipedia, or in the printable version) which has a table of contents, to a **PDF file** with a **working table of contents**, ie. a one that will forward you to the **right page** once you **click corresponding item** or subitem.

So far I have been able to convert the page to PDF via varius mechanisms, but none of them produced a working ToC. Can you advise?

Comment: I doubt you will be able to get this working. I have been searching for a similar tool, (to convert a word document with working index to pdf retaining the index) and I ended up using a 2nd tool to recreate the index inside the pdf. Is it required for it to be a .pdf file? Can't it be an .mht file? That one is likely to work out of the box.

Comment: As long as I can view it in an Android tablet...

Comment: Yes, you can: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tflare.mhtviewer

Comment: even for basic mediawiki to html I can't get it to produce a table of contents. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

Given with what you want, the best option would be to export the webpage as an .mht (html archive) file.

To do this, open the page in any browser (most major browsers support this), and go to `file` > `save as` and from the file type list, select *.mht.

If your browser does not support mht for some reason, Internet Explorer does support it.

Now, you can copy this mht file to your phone or tablet and use mhtviewer (available on Google Play) to view it.